# Ignore DataMember at runtime -WCF [IgnoreDataMember]

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I was wondering if there is a way to add the attribute [IgnoreDataMember] at runtime in case a catch is triggeres. I have the return object having a custom error object within it and I want to ignore all the other DataMembers if the error DataMember is populated. I dont want to initially add [IgnoreDataMember] in case the response comes back successful. Only do this if the Error object is populated.

```
public TransactionResultDto createAccount(AccountActivationDto account)
{

    try
    {
        DatabaseHelper.CheckForDatabaseAndCreate();
        AccountDto newAccount = new PendingAccountDto(account);
        response = DatabaseHelper.CreatePendingAccount(newAccount);
        ActivationEmailer.SendEmail(newAccount);
        PendingAccountDto pendingAccount = (PendingAccountDto)newAccount;
        return response;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorMessageDto error = new ErrorMessageDto();
        response.Error = ExceptionBuilder.LogErrors(ex);
        return response;
    }
}
```

DataContract

```
namespace developer1SVC.Core.Dto.Transaction
{
    [DataContract]
    public  class TransactionResultDto
    {
        private bool transactionSuccess;
        private string transactionDescription;
        private string transactionValue;
        private DateTime transactionDate;

        [DataMember]
        public bool TransactionSuccess
        {
            get { return transactionSuccess; }
            set { transactionSuccess = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string TransactionDescription
        {
            get { return transactionDescription; }
            set { transactionDescription = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string TransactionValue
        {
          get {return transactionValue;}
          set { transactionValue = value;}
        }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime TransactionDate
        {
            get {return transactionDate; }
            set { transactionDate = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public ErrorMessageDto Error { get; set; }
}
}
```

So if the error object comes back with something, thats all i want to display in the client. Nothing else.

help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible. Why don't you recreate an instance of the TransactionResultDto and initialise the ErrorMessageDto property and return that.

Comment: Have you looked at using FaultContract in WCF, this is the preferred way of returning exceptions. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/SunilBabuYLV/using-the-fault-contracts-soap-faults-in-wcf-programming/